# Посоветуйте адекватное средство моделирования на IDEF0, можно online

Tags: база-данных

Посоветуйте адекватное средство моделирования баз данных на IDEF0. Можно online.

Answer (score 2):

Товарищ, мне кажется, что вы путаете методологии. IDEF0 предназначен для моделирования бизнес-процессов. Может быть вы имели ввиду IDEF1X ?

В бытность студентом и на первой работе использовал для этого [ERWin](http://erwin.com/). Он как раз моделирует по методологии IDEF1X.

Сейчас на второй работе использую MS [Visio 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visio/). Вполне хватает, а если ещё плагинами для работы с базой обвесить - так вообще супер.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler - бесплатный (logical model, relational model, domain, data types, ...)